# kotlin null pointer exception in default value

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, default-value

I have code like this one:

```
@Service
class SomeClass (
    private val departmentClient : DepartmentClient
) {
    fun someFunction(
        employee: Employee,
        department: Department = departmentClient.getById(employee.departmentId)
    ): Unit {
        here my code
    }
}

data class Employee(val departmentId: Long, val id: Long)
data class Department(val id: Long)

@Service
class DepartmentClient() {
    fun getById(id: Long): Department
}
```

When I don't pass the department parameter in someFunction, I expect that `departmentClient.getById(employee.departmentId)` will be called. The problem is that in some cases I get a null pointer exception in this line, but in others, I don't.
All dependencies are injected by Spring.

Comment: can you share the implementation of `departmentClient.getById()`? For me it looks like the error might be in that function. its return value is a non-nullable `Department`, though it might not find the department wiht the given id and return `null` instead. That could happen of you use a Jave library to search for the department (e.g. in a database) and this library returns null in the case there is no department with hat id.

Comment: No, in the implementation, it calls another microservice, using the rest template. And if it doesn't find it throws an exception.

Comment: Where does the rest template come from?

Answer (score 0):

The function `getById` is probably defined wrongly and at runtime it hits with a null-pointer-exception. Where does this function come from?

It should look like this:

```
class DepartmentClient() {
    fun getById(id: Long): Department?
}
```

That would mean you need to deal with `department: Department?` in `here my code`.

Comment: see the comment, please. This function can't throw a null pointer.

Comment: is the exception thrown by the "rest microservice" handled correctly or does this convert into a null value returned by that `departmentClient.getById` call?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when You assigned a variable null value
You can fix the problem like this by using '?' or '?.' (safety operator)
by putting '?' after a Type (Department)

```
fun someFunction(
        employee: Employee,
        department: Department? = departmentClient.getById(employee.departmentId)
    ): Unit {
        here my code
    }
```